# Find out which port number an RDS Security Group is attached with?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, rds

I want to find out to which port number an RDS security group is attached to.

```
security_groups = rds_conn.get_all_dbsecurity_groups()
for sg in security_groups:
    print sg
    for ip_range in sg.ip_ranges:
        #Report which port this is attached to
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: I am not able to find the port number, which is attached to that security group.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the previous solution. Try this

```
security_groups = rds_conn.get_all_dbsecurity_groups()
for sg in security_groups:
    for r in sg.rules:
        print rule.ip_protocol, rule.from_port, rule.to_port, rule.grants
```

Comment: How to extract port number from it??

Comment: @upaangsaxena Don't think about v1 or v2 just leave it. Just edit your previous code.

Comment: I am getting an error that rules is not there. And also, its not showing in Debugging mode too.

Comment: @upaangsaxena For my db instance it uses the vpc security groups that is ec2 security groups. Let me know whether you have separate security groups for rds or not?

Comment: it is showing error in this:     
for r in sg.rules:
AttributeError: 'DBSecurityGroup' object has no attribute 'rules'

Comment: And, this thing only works on EC2 sg's. I need to fetch RDS SG.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75171/discussion-between-upaang-saxena-and-sailesh).